# Weighting a machine learning prediction with a cost of a false negative

Tags: machine-learning, classification, threshold

I have a classifier that predicts whether or not a part will be bad. These parts are almost the same but vary only slightly. However the importance of every part is different. For e.g. one part is used in 5 different machines while the next is used in the manufacture of a 100. The second part clearly has an additional risk associated with it. I have a model that predicts whether or not a part will fail which is thresholded reasonably well. How do I incorporate this cost of error simply. I would not like to re-train the model and have only RF/SVM's available.

Comment: What exactly do you want to calculate? The estimated cost of failure? Then you can apply the cost function to the results of your prediction. You don't need to modify the failure predictor.

Comment: I would like to re-weight the prediction to incorporate the cost of failure.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the problem correctly (question is not very strictly posed) - you are asking how to make the particular machine learning models focus more on some of the training samples. There are at least two possible ways of doing such thing:

- Many existing machine learning models have "sample-weight" which can force the model to "pay more attention" to particular training samples while allowing to missclassify those who are less important. In particular, SVM has such feature, in [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) you simply set `sample_weight` while creating the `SVM` classifier
- If you use some kind of cross validation for parameter search, you can use weighted evaluation function, which will use the knowledge of "cost" of particular false positive, as a result - you will select parameters that are best in sense of this weighted measure

Answer (score 0):

If the cost of failure is known, why do you want to incorporate it into your predictor? Just apply it to your output.